# PHP Function Output Screwy

Tags: php

I am trying to have the function print the # of sub items in each parent item but can't seem to get that to work. For some reason `print_r(count($arr[$key]['children']))` is outputting first, then looping through the rest and putting a number 1 where it is supposed to be returning a count.

```
function create_list($arr)
{
    $html = "";
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        if(count($value['children']) > 0) {
            $html .= $value['name'].' (' . print_r(count($arr[$key]['children'])) . ')<ul>';

            foreach($value['children'] AS $child) {
                $html .= '  <li><a id="'.$child['menu_item_id'].'">'.$child['name'].'</a></li>';
            }

            $html .= '  </ul>
                        ';
        } else{
            $html .= '  <a class="menuitem" id="'.$value['menu_item_id'].'">'.$value['name'].'</a>';
        }
    }

    return $html;
}

    echo create_list($menu_items);
```

Outputs the following:

```
22Main Task (1)
 o second task
 o sub task
George (1)
 o test
 o tester
```

Where it says 22MainTask, the 22 is the results from the count from each root level item. What is the proper way to return a count on that? I am hoping to be able to also print (2/5) tasks complete type, but if I could at least get it to return an accurate count that would be a great first step.

Comment: why are you using `print_r`? why not just `count($arr[$key]['children'])`?  you are already concatenating this within a string so `print_r` is redundant.  Also, `print_r` (as well as `var_dump`) output straight to the browser, i.e. bypasses html rendering, so that would be why `22` appears before your html

Comment: You should really be using `htmlspecialchars()` around arbitrary data used in the context of HTML.  At best, you're creating invalid HTML once in awhile, and at worse you are open to XSS attacks.

Comment: Thanks Celeriko, your way worked also, but I couldn't mark it as correct since it was just a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a second parameter to return the value instead of printing it immediately.

> print_r($data, true)

In your example, it prints a count of "1" because print_r returns true (which is converted to "1") if you don't provide the second parameter as true.